# Cannot understand hoow to recursively merge sort

Tags: c++11, mergesort

Currently self-learning C++ with Daniel Liang's Introduction to C++.

On the topic of the merge sort, I cannot seem to understand how his code is recursively calling itself.

I understand the general concept of the merge sort, but I am having trouble understanding this code specifically.

In this example, we first pass the list 1, 7, 3, 4, 9, 3, 3, 1, 2, and its size (9) to the mergeSort function.
From there, we divide the list into two until the array size reaches 1. In this case, we would get: 1,7,3,4 -> 1,7 -> 1. We then move onto the merge sorting the second half. The second half array would be 7 in this case. We merge the two arrays [1] and [7] and proceed to delete the two arrays that were dynamically allocated to prevent any memory leak.

The part I don't understand is how does this code run from here? After delete[] firstHalf and delete[] secondHalf. From my understanding, shouldn't there be another mergeSort function call in order to merge sort the new firstHalf and secondHalf?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Function prototype
void arraycopy(int source[], int sourceStartIndex,
  int target[], int targetStartIndex, int length);

void merge(int list1[], int list1Size,
  int list2[], int list2Size, int temp[]);

// The function for sorting the numbers 
void mergeSort(int list[], int arraySize)
{
  if (arraySize > 1)
  {
    // Merge sort the first half
    int* firstHalf = new int[arraySize / 2];
    arraycopy(list, 0, firstHalf, 0, arraySize / 2);
    mergeSort(firstHalf, arraySize / 2);

    // Merge sort the second half
    int secondHalfLength = arraySize - arraySize / 2;
    int* secondHalf = new int[secondHalfLength];
    arraycopy(list, arraySize / 2, secondHalf, 0, secondHalfLength);
    mergeSort(secondHalf, secondHalfLength);

    // Merge firstHalf with secondHalf
    merge(firstHalf, arraySize / 2, secondHalf, secondHalfLength,
      list);

    delete [] firstHalf;
    delete [] secondHalf;
  }
}

void merge(int list1[], int list1Size,
  int list2[], int list2Size, int temp[])
{
  int current1 = 0; // Current index in list1
  int current2 = 0; // Current index in list2
  int current3 = 0; // Current index in temp

  while (current1 < list1Size && current2 < list2Size)
  {
    if (list1[current1] < list2[current2])
      temp[current3++] = list1[current1++];
    else
      temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
  }

  while (current1 < list1Size)
    temp[current3++] = list1[current1++];

  while (current2 < list2Size)
    temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
}

void arraycopy(int source[], int sourceStartIndex,
  int target[], int targetStartIndex, int length)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    target[i + targetStartIndex] = source[i + sourceStartIndex];
  }
}

int main()
{
  const int SIZE = 9;
  int list[] = {1, 7, 3, 4, 9, 3, 3, 1, 2};
  mergeSort(list, SIZE);
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    cout << list[i] << " ";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Each instance of merge sort on the first half will eventually return to call merge sort again for the second half. The sequence of events is depth first, left first.

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding, shouldn't there be another mergeSort function
> call in order to merge sort the new firstHalf and secondHalf?

It is happening implicitly during the recursive call. When you reach these two lines:

```
delete [] firstHalf;
delete [] secondHalf;
```

It means that one call to `mergeSort` is completed. If this call belongs to merging a first half, then code starts from the line after, i.e. these lines:

```
// Merge sort the second half
int secondHalfLength = arraySize - arraySize / 2;
...
```

But, if this call belongs to merging of the second half, then the control goes back to the line just after that call, i.e. these lines:

```
// Merge firstHalf with secondHalf
merge(firstHalf, arraySize / 2, secondHalf, secondHalfLength,
  list);
```

And everything if doing well as planned.